# CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, deferred

I am developing spider project and I have moved to a new computer. Now I am installing everything and I encounter problem with Twisted. I have read about this bug and I have installed pywin32 and then also WinPython, but it doesn't help. I have tried to update Twisted with this command

```
pip install Twisted --update
```

as advised in the forum, but it says that pip install doesn't have --update option. I have also run

```
python python27\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

but with no success. This is my error:

```
G:\Job_vacancies\Python\vacancies>scrapy crawl jobs
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: vacancies)
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'va
cancies.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['vacancies.spiders'], 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'BO
T_NAME': 'vacancies'}
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsol
e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_comm
and
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run

    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in
unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in
_inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 83, in _create_en
gine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 66, in __init
__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line
65, in __init__
    self.handlers = DownloadHandlers(crawler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.p
y", line 23, in __init__
    cls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_ob
ject
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\s3.py", li
ne 6, in <module>
    from .http import HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py",
line 5, in <module>
    from .http11 import HTTP11DownloadHandler as HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py"
, line 15, in <module>
    from scrapy.xlib.tx import Agent, ProxyAgent, ResponseDone, \
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\xlib\tx\__init__.py", line 3, in <m
odule>
    from twisted.web import client
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 42, in <modul
e>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, SSL4ClientEndpoin
t
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 34, i
n <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <m
odule>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 7,
in <module>
    import win32api
exceptions.ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
.
2015-10-06 09:12:53 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

And this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding=UTF-8  
import scrapy, urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin
from vacancies.items import JobItem

#We need that in order to force Slovenian pages instead of English pages. It happened at "http://www.g-gmi.si/gmiweb/" that only English pages were found and no Slovenian.
#from scrapy.conf import settings
#settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'sl',}
#settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'sl','en':q=0.8,}







class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "jobs"

    #Test sample of SLO companies 
    start_urls = [

        "http://www.g-gmi.si/gmiweb/",
    ]
    #Result of the programme is this list of job vacancies webpages.
    jobs_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):

        response.selector.remove_namespaces() 



        #We take all urls, they are marked by "href". These are either webpages on our website either new websites.
        urls = response.xpath('//@href').extract()


        #Base url.
        base_url = get_base_url(response) 


        #Loop through all urls on the webpage.
        for url in urls:

            #If url represents a picture, a document, a compression ... we ignore it. We might have to change that because some companies provide job vacancies information in PDF.
            if url.endswith((
                #images
                '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.eps', '.ico', '.svg', '.tif', '.tiff',
                '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.PNG', '.GIF', '.EPS', '.ICO', '.SVG', '.TIF', '.TIFF',

                #documents
                '.xls', '.ppt', '.doc', '.xlsx', '.pptx', '.docx', '.txt', '.csv', '.pdf', '.pd', 
                '.XLS', '.PPT', '.DOC', '.XLSX', '.PPTX', '.DOCX', '.TXT', '.CSV', '.PDF', '.PD', 

                #music and video
                '.mp3', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.ai', '.avi', '.swf',
                '.MP3', '.MP4', '.MPG', '.AI', '.AVI', '.SWF',

                #compressions and other
                '.zip', '.rar', '.css', '.flv', '.php',
                '.ZIP', '.RAR', '.CSS', '.FLV', '.PHP',


            )):
                continue


            #If url includes characters like ?, %, &, # ... it is LIKELY NOT to be the one we are looking for and we ignore it. 
            #However in this case we exclude good urls like http://www.mdm.si/company#employment
            if any(x in url for x in ['?', '%', '&', '#']):
                continue

            #Ignore ftp.
            if url.startswith("ftp"):
                continue

            #We need to save original url for xpath, in case we change it later (join it with base_url)
            url_xpath = url

            #If url doesn't start with "http", it is relative url, and we add base url to get absolute url.
            # -- It is true, that we may get some strange urls, but it is fine for now.            
            if not (url.startswith("http")):

                url = urljoin(base_url,url)


            #We don't want to go to other websites. We want to stay on our website, so we keep only urls with domain (netloc) of the company we are investigating.         
            if (urlparse(url).netloc == urlparse(base_url).netloc):



                #The main part. We look for webpages, whose urls include one of the employment words as strings.

                # -- Instruction. 
                # -- Users in other languages, please insert employment words in your own language, like jobs, vacancies, career, employment ... --
                if any(x in url for x in [

                    'zaposlovanje',
                    'Zaposlovanje',

                    'zaposlitev',
                    'Zaposlitev',

                    'zaposlitve',
                    'Zaposlitve',

                    'zaposlimo',
                    'Zaposlimo',

                    'kariera',
                    'Kariera',

                    'delovna-mesta',

                    'delovna_mesta',

                    'pridruzi-se',
                    'pridruzi_se',   

                    'prijava-za-delo',
                    'prijava_za_delo',   

                    'oglas',
                    'Oglas',

                    'iscemo',
                    'Iscemo',        

                    'careers',
                    'Careers',

                    'jobs',
                    'Jobs',

                    'employment',                                      
                    'Employment',      


                ]):
                    #This is additional filter, suggested by Dan Wu, to improve accuracy. We will check the text of the url as well.
                    texts = response.xpath('//a[@href="%s"]/text()' % url_xpath).extract() 

                    #1. Texts are empty.
                    if texts == []:

                        print "Ni teksta za url: " + str(url)


                        #We found url that includes one of the magic words and also the text includes a magic word. 
                        #We check url, if we have found it before. If it is new, we add it to the list "jobs_urls".
                        if url not in self.jobs_urls:


                            self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                            item = JobItem()
                            #item["text"] = text
                            item["url"] = url



                            #We return the item.
                            yield item



                    # 2. There are texts, one or more.
                    else:


                        #For the same partial url several texts are possible.
                        for text in texts:


                            if any(x in text for x in [

                                'zaposlovanje',
                                'Zaposlovanje',

                                'zaposlitev',
                                'Zaposlitev',

                                'zaposlitve',
                                'Zaposlitve',

                                'zaposlimo',
                                'Zaposlimo',
                                'ZAPOSLIMO',

                                'kariera',
                                'Kariera',

                                'delovna-mesta',

                                'delovna_mesta',

                                'pridruzi-se',
                                'pridruzi_se',     

                                'oglas',
                                'Oglas',     

                                'iscemo',
                                'Iscemo',
                                'ISCEMO',


                                'careers',
                                'Careers',

                                'jobs',
                                'Jobs',

                                'employment',                                      
                                'Employment',    



                            ]):

                                #We found url that includes one of the magic words and also the text includes a magic word. 
                                #We check url, if we have found it before. If it is new, we add it to the list "jobs_urls".
                                if url not in self.jobs_urls:


                                    self.jobs_urls.append(url)
                                    item = JobItem()
                                    item["text"] = text
                                    item["url"] = url



                                    #We return the item.
                                    yield item

                #We don't put "else" sentence because we want to further explore the employment webpage to find possible new employment webpages.
                #We keep looking for employment webpages, until we reach the DEPTH, that we have set in settings.py. 
                yield Request(url, callback = self.parse)




      # We run the programme in the command line with this command: 

      #      scrapy crawl jobs -o jobs.csv -t csv --logfile log.txt

      # We get two output files
      #  1) jobs.csv
      #  2) log.txt


      # Then we manually put one of employment urls from jobs.csv into read.py
```

I would be glad if you could give some advice on how to run this thing. Thank you, Marko

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always install stuff into a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  Once you've got a virtualenv and it's active, do:

```
pip install --upgrade twisted pypiwin32
```

and you should get the depenendency that makes Twisted support stdio on the Windows platform.

To get *all* the goodies you might try

```
pip install --upgrade twisted[windows_platform]
```

but you may run into problems with `gmp.h` if you try that, and you don't need most of it to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for using Twisted!  If this answer solves your problem, can you click the green checkmark ("accept") and maybe upvote? :)

Comment: Hi @Glyph, I upvoted and there is a green tick. I am however using Twisted because the programme requires, not because I am fan of Twisted :)

Comment: Well, thanks for submitting to the grim dystopian future where Twisted reigns supreme, willingly or not :).

Comment: Well Gylph, I don't have an opinion about Twisted because I don't really know it, but why would the future with Twisted be grim, why not bright ? :)

Comment: I've checked it ... I wouldn't be having fun with destruction of the Sun however ... some smart remarks about people, that is more fun for me ...